# RCP product no longer starts

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp

After editing a number of plugins in an RCP project, the deployed app no longer starts. The error message in the .metadata/.log file is

```
!MESSAGE Product com.company.xyz.app.product could not be found.
```

I have gone back over the changes I made but cannot identify anything which looks suspicious.

If I start the app directly from the Product Editor it works. If I export the product and run the exported app it doesn't work.

There are 320 plugins in the product configuration and 322 in the export. The two extra plugins are for `equinox.launcher` which I assume are generated during the export. Otherwise the list of plugins is identical.

I tried exporting with and without a Java runtime but the result is the same.

I tried starting with `-debug` and `debugConsole` but there was no useful information.

What can I do to get more information about the cause of the problem?

Comment: Look in the .log file in the workspace .metadata directory to see if there is a message. If you are specifying Start Levels in the .product file make sure you have all the recommended levels (click 'Add Recommended') these have changed in Eclipse 2018-12

Comment: The message in the log file is in the body of the question. It is the only error message there. 'Product could not be found'. I also did 'Add required plugins'. Nothing was added. No start levels are defined - all default.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was caused by me adding a dependency to one of my plugins. That dependency has a dependency which I have in my eclipse installation but not on the build server. Therefore I was able to test without any issues but the built version was missing a plugin.

Shame that no hints were given by the RCP on startup...